# PIP3: Install Offline & Update Older Library

Tags: pi-4, python-3, pip

Tried these commands to install an uncompressed package with pip3:

`pip3 install --no-index --find-links=/home/pi/Downloads/GitHub/cryptography cryptography`

`sudo pip3 install -U --no-index --find-links=/home/pi/Downloads/GitHub/cryptography cryptography`

Getting the message:

> Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.6.1)

The library version is 3.4.7, but the minimum required is 3.2.

Comment: If you're trying to replace the same or an older version you'll have to `pip uninstall` the installed version first.

Comment: Will try that, this is on a Raspberry Pi 4 running the RPi OS. I've seen a lot of variations on the pip3 commands while searching online (some probably mistakes).

Comment: (sudo) pip3 uninstall cryptography -> Not uninstalling cryptography at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr - Can't uninstall 'cryptography'. No files were found to uninstall.

Comment: The package was installed using APT, so you can't uninstall it using pip. Use a virtual environment.

Comment: Ok. Using show command for both package managers, pip3 provides more info, while apt -> N: Unable to locate package cryptography N: Unable to locate package cryptography E: No packages found. Curious. When I followed the instructions for online installation the first time, there were no issues, but can't depend on having an Internet connection.

Comment: Like I said earlier, use a virtual environment. If you're _really sure_ you want to remove the APT version, the package name is probably `python3-cryptography`, not `cryptography`.

Comment: Will find out how a virtual environment (venv) works.